# link my mysql database with my webOS application for tv lg

Tags: webos

Good evening,
I'm trying to create an IPK web OS application for an LG TV like in the airport, and recover the data saved in the MySQL database,
I installed the environment there is only html, CSS, and it doesn’t support PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a web-based type of the application instead of fully packed. So, you can upload your website with all necessary environment to a test link (ex test.com) and then use window.location in your index.html file in IPK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = 'http://test.com/';
</script>
```